# Magento 2 event/observer for create shipment

Tags: events, magento2, observers

I'm trying to send an SMS notification to the client after creating a shipment.

In M1 I can do that with this event:

```
<sales_order_shipment_save_after>
```

But in Magento 2 there is no event triggering after creating the shipment.

Answer (score 4):

you can use **sales_order_shipment_save_after** event

for this you need to create etc/events.xml file to define your event

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_shipment_save_after">
        <observer name="emizentechshipment" instance="Emizentech\MyModule\Observer\ProcessShipment" />
    </event>
</config>
```

than you need to create Observer\ProcessShipment.php file

```
<?php
namespace Emizentech\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProcessShipment implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        // your code for sms here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot Emizen, but it's not working, I thing ```sales_order_shipment_save_after``` not triggering totally, I tried it in two cases, 
1-etc/events.xml
2-etc/adminthtml/events.xml
and in both of them it's not triggering.

Comment: @Emadjag it works perfectly , let me know if you are getting any issues
 Make Sure to clear cache from : bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Thanks a lot Emizen, it's working fine, after trying too much my self i got solution from yours.Thanks again

Comment: @EmizenTech I am able to generate the invoice programmatically but after redirecting to the order view page I am getting this error ----> adminhtml/session

Comment: @EmizenTech https://stackoverflow.com/a/65968400/3690413